# How to prevent stuck processes caused by scripts executed by cron

Tags: linux, cron

I have some scripts that run in crontab that I believe are getting 'stuck' and never properly exiting the process.

I found the user that has these scripts in crontab had 4096 processes in "ps -aux" output and most were old (several days or more) and probably stuck since they should not stay open like that.  Due to this I was getting "Resource temporarily unavailable" errors in the cron log.

What I cant figure out is why these are getting stuck like that.

Here is an example of one I think is stuck

```
apache    6487  0.0  0.0 113176  1224 ?        Ss   Dec18   0:00 /bin/sh -c /app/www/scripts/migrate_enhanced.pl > /dev/null 2>&1
# pstree -pl 6487
sh(6487)---migrate_enhance(6489)---redshacl(6529)---ping(6530)
# cat /proc/6530/stack
[<ffffffff82c2b100>] __skb_wait_for_more_packets+0x120/0x180
[<ffffffff82c2b4cf>] __skb_recv_datagram+0x6f/0xd0
[<ffffffff82c2b573>] skb_recv_datagram+0x43/0x60
[<ffffffff82cb0999>] raw_recvmsg+0xa9/0x200
[<ffffffff82cc1220>] inet_recvmsg+0x80/0xb0
[<ffffffff82c1a4f5>] sock_recvmsg+0xc5/0x100
[<ffffffff82c1b673>] ___sys_recvmsg+0x133/0x2d0
[<ffffffff82c1cb91>] __sys_recvmsg+0x51/0x90
[<ffffffff82c1cbe2>] SyS_recvmsg+0x12/0x20
[<ffffffff82d75d9b>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
#
```

Comment: Can you run `ps` again to get the full command line of ping(6530) ? By default, ping runs forever, until interrupted with a signal, unless an option like `-c` is passed to it.

Comment: I found ping in the PS doing this:
/user/bin/ping mydevice 1
I think the trailing 1 might be the issue.  This script (i inherited from a previous programmer) was originally used on a solaris machine but the one it is on now is linux.  I am going to adjust the code on that particular script to linux (ping mydevice -c 1) to see if that helps this one.

Comment: @JasonM Make that `ping -c 1 mydevice` to have the arguments in some sort of proper order (options before operands).

Comment: Can we assume that your issue has gone away?